# Xcode: Require workspace instead or project?

Tags: xcode

I can't count how many times I've opened a Xcode project instead of a workspace and spent a half hour trying to figure out what I've done wrong because none of the dependancies can be found.

Is there a way to detect this and generate a helpful error message in my compiler prefix?

I could try importing one of the headers that isn't always available, but I'd prefer something more direct and obvious if possible. (Mostly because if I rely on a particular header, that only really checks one package. It also imports the header so I don't need to `#import` it from my other code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a pre-action Build phase script in your scheme to check the build path and take some action if it's wrong. In your workspace, you can specify a custom build path for workspace-wide stuff. If the path doesn't match, you know your target is being built from project only. (It's unfortunate that Apple doesn't provide an environment variable for the workspace and that even workspace-level schemes give the target's project as the project path.) But this is fiddly and seems gross. You ought to feel dirty even considering it, and guilty at having caused me to write it. What would your mother think?

Another (better, IMO) approach is to Manage Schemes when opened as Workspace and change the Container for all schemes to your workspace vs. project-level. This ensures there are no schemes available to build if the project itself is opened. You'll see "No Scheme" and any attempt to build, run, whatever, will give you an error beep.

Comment: The Build Phase approach is exactly the sort of sick insanity I expect from you. But on the other hand, the approach of removing schemes from the project is the sort of brilliance I would expect from you. Well done all around. :)

Comment: Thanks, I work very hard to please you both here and on Twitter. ;-)